# with glfw -3.2.1 inside my work directory ,how to compile with it using makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, glfw

I want to compile a program with makefile as bellow:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -I/example_01/glew -I/example_01/glfw-3.2.1 -Wno-deprecated-declarations
LDFLAGS = -lGL -lGLEW -glfw

RM = /bin/rm -f 
all: main 
main: example_01/src/example_01.o 
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o as1 example_01/src/example_01.o $(LDFLAGS) 
example_00/example_00.o: example_01/example_01.cpp
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c example_01/src/example_01.cpp -o example_01/src/example_01.o
clean: 
$(RM) *.o example_01/src/*.o as1
```

But there's error :

```
fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

my makefile located in

```
graphics/example_01
```

glfw-3.2.1 and glew file located in

```
graphics/example_01/example_01
```

glfw3.h located in

```
graphics/example_01/example_01/glfw-3.2.1/include/GLFW
```

example_01.cpp located in

```
graphics/example_01/example_01/src
```

So how to compile ? Thanks!

[inside glfw-3.2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svv0I.png)

[inside GLFW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntvOC.png)

Comment: Could you show us what the contents of the `glfw-3.2.1/GLFW` directory look like?

Comment: @Xirema hi. I post the pics. sorry that I made a mistake in the former post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your include directory is wrong.

```
CFLAGS = -g -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -I/example_01/glew -I/example_01/glfw-3.2.1 -Wno-deprecated-declarations
```

You should change `-I/example_01/glfw-3.2.1` to `-I/example_01/glfw-3.2.1/include`

It is possible that you'll need to make a similar change to the GLEW include directory.

Comment: it still has the same error: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
 #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

Comment: @tiger What about `-I/graphics/example_01/glfw-3.2.1/include`? The underlying problem is that the compiler can't find the include files, so you need to make sure they're correctly included.

Comment: @tiger You need to get your includes correct. Getting it correct on my end, on a completely different machine (and probably a different OS) is not going to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi. I downloaded another homework file, and it is compiled ok. So Ill just used another file. Thanks!